# Active Desktop Recovery

Tags: windows-xp

This one's new to me.

I downloaded and installed the VB.Net version 3.5 updates, and got some complaints about my printer drivers, which I ignored.  My system auto-rebooted without asking, and then came up with am "Active Desktop Recovery" background screen (everything still works normally).  So when I tried to "restore my active desktop" ( a button on the background screen) it claims a script error.

Okay, fine, I wasn't using the active desktop anyhow, so I decided to turn it off.  Go to the Display Properties window, and WTF!  The Desktop tab is gone!

Anybody know the fix for this, or even a workaround??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like malware, perhaps trying to hide whatever changes it made to your desktop and prevent you from undoing them. Give your favourite anti-malware a go.

Afterwards, to restore the tab and fix the recover button thingie there's a few MSKBs: [929200](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922370) and [929200](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=929200).

Answer (score 0):

Set the decimal value to 0 under the value DeskHtmlVersion in key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\SafeMode\Components.